# C# Emailing to the default profile address using Outlook Object Library 12.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Should be a simple question. Using C#, all I want to do is just email to the email address associated to the default profile, how do I do this? I have the following code setup:

```
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook._NameSpace oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder oOutboxFolder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);   
        oNameSpace.Logon(null, null, false, false);
        Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMailItem.To = oMailItem.SenderEmailAddress; //this is where it does not work.
        oMailItem.Subject = "subject";
        oMailItem.Body = "body";
        oMailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder = oOutboxFolder;
```

I thought by using `oMailItem.SenderEmailAddress`, this would work. But it doesn't. Can anyone shed some light on this? All I want to do is send it to myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll find answers here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3f5ec8bc-ec3d-4dda-96d4-d5dabecf0395/

Answer (score 0):

try oNameSpace.CurrentUser.Address; it will work to get sender email address